# Save and continue button on Nintex form not working on form with validations

Tags: forms, validation

I have created a form with required fields on Nintex 2013. Its a long form therefore I have added save and continue button so that users can save the form and fill it up later. When I click on save and continue button it highlights the required fields, and doesnt let me save the form. Is there a way I can save the form with required fields?

Thanks,
Ralive